# Find the max height of skewed subtree in BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Here are my attempts to do it... But it doesn't work, can anyone help me?
I do it postfix (hp, hl - height of right and left subtree), (ok_l, ok_p - variables to controle if until now it was a skewed), when it stops being skewed - I stop increasing the height;

```
void Spacer (node *d, int *height, int *ok) {
    if(d) {
        int hp = 0;
        int hl = 0;;
        int ok_p = 1;
        int ok_l = 1;;
        if(d->l_syn)   Spacer(d->l_syn, &hl, &ok_l);//postfix
        if(d->p_syn)  Spacer(d->p_syn, &hp, &ok_p);
        printf("%d %d/   ", d->w, *height);
        if((!d->l_syn||!d->p_syn)&&*ok==1)  (*height)++;
        if(d->l_syn&&d->p_syn)   {
            *height = max(hl,hp); 
            *ok = 0;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct node *d = NULL;
    int maximum = 0; //maksymalny rozmiar dotychczasowego poddrzewa cienkiego
    int height = 0;
    int czy_lewy = 0;
    int ok = 1;
    
    //////// TESTY//////////////
    d = insert (d, 9);
    insert (d, 6);
    insert (d, 8);
    insert (d, 5);
    insert (d, 4);
    insert (d,3);
    //insert (d,6);
    /////////////////////////////
    
    Spacer(d, &height, &ok);

    printf("%d ",height);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not right. `height` can never get more than 1, as `(*height)++;` will always be executed on a `height` that is zero, and by induction that means that `max(hl,hp)` can also never be more than 1.

The algorithm could be like this:

```c
void Spacer (node *d, int *height, int *ok) {
    *ok = 1; // default (empty tree is skewed)
    *height = -1; // default (empty tree has height -1)
    if (d) {
        // No need to initialise -- they are output parameters
        int hp, hl, ok_p, ok_l;

        // We can recurse also with a NULL child
        Spacer(d->l_syn, &hl, &ok_l);
        Spacer(d->p_syn, &hp, &ok_p);

        // Current node is root of a skewed tree if, and only when:
        // * It does not have two non-null children, AND
        // * Its children represent skewed subtree(s)
        *ok = (!d->l_syn || !d->p_syn) && min(ok_l, ok_p);
        // If OK, we can extend with 1
        *height = max(hl, hp) + *ok;

        printf("%d %d/   ", d->w, *height);
    }
}
```